# Python Selenium Explicit WebDriverWait function only works with presence_of_element_located

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium WebDriverWait in Python to wait for items to load on a webpage , however, using any expected condition apart from **presence_of_element_located** seems to result in the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

I thought it might be linked to the site I was trying against , however I get the same error on any site - see snippit below where I have replaced **presence_of_element_located** with **visibility_of_element_located** and am trying to confirm visibility of the search box on python.org.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,"q")))
    element.send_keys("pycon")
    element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

The Full stack trace is as below , Any help would be appreciated !

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\test.py", line 51, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,"q")))
  File "C:\Development\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b3-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Development\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b3-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 78, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
  File "C:\Development\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b3-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 98, in _element_if_visible
    return element if element.is_displayed() == visibility else False
  File "C:\Development\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b3-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 353, in is_displayed
    self)
  File "C:\Development\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b3-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 465, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Development\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b3-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Development\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.0b3-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical
```

*Update - > After a few comments below i have done some testing on versions and browsers and this issue seems isolated to Python 3 and Firefox , the script works with Python 2.7 and works on both versions of python for Chrome webdriver .*

Comment: I believe you have to select a web driver aka chrome , firefox etc

Comment: @w-enzo OP already selected Firefox as the web driver.

Comment: Copy/Pasted same code, it works for me. I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

These minor changes work for me.

1. visibility_of_element_located ===> presence_of_element_located
2. driver.quit() ===> driver.close()

See the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"q")))
    element.send_keys("pycon")
    element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Comment: There is difference between visibility and presence so one cannot be substitute of other.

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasted the same code and it works. 
Dint have enough repo to post comments so had to put it in answer section.