# Accurately detect page with AJAX load time in Python using Selenium

Tags: python, performance, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to accurately detect page load times on a company website I'm working on. I've decided to try and do this using python and selenium so I can automate it. However, I've seemed to have hit a wall since I'm unable to get a reliable page load time. The culprit appears to be the fact that we don't consider the page "loaded" until a ~3 second ajax call finishes. Yet, Selenium considers the page loaded when the DOM fully loads before that, which is not the load time we're looking for. I've read online I can use the WebDriverWait function to poll for an element that appears after the ajax executes. I should be able to do this as new elements are created after the ajax call, however, I've noticed online that it has a polling frequency of 500ms, which is far too large for me. I'm trying to very accurately determine page load times and 500ms is a large margin of error. I couldn't find anything online for how to change the default polling frequency in python, just similar stuff in Java that I can't decipher. If you know how to decrease the polling frequency by a lot or have a better idea of how to get the accurate page load time with Ajax with a margin of error around ~50ms please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my project I wrote such a function:

```
def wait_for(condition_function, *args):
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() < start_time + 10:
        if condition_function(*args):
            return True
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    raise TimeoutException(
        'Timeout waiting for {}'.format(condition_function.__name__)
    )
```

to later use it like this:

```
wait_for(obj_has_gone_stale, login_btn)
```

where `login_btn` is a Selenium object and `obj_has_gone_stale` is a function that tries to find object and catches a `StaleElementReferenceException`. It looks like this:

```
def obj_has_gone_stale(obj):
    try:
        # poll the link with an arbitrary call
        obj.find_elements_by_id('doesnt-matter')
        return False
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        return True
```

With this approach you can set `time.sleep()` inside `wait_for` for any time you want. But don't forget to take into consideration that `obj.find_elements_by_id('doesnt-matter')` may also take some time to execute . No sure if it is much better that Selenium built-in `wait for presence` as I wrote `wait_for` for scenarios where the `obj` has to disappear and not to appear. But you may write something similar to `obj_has_gone_stale` but  `obj_has_rendered`. It basically has to try to access `obj` and see if it has been rendered on the page and return true. Then pass the function to `wait_for`.

Comment: If the condition is not complex like it's just find_elements_by_id, then I suggest you using selenium's WebDriverWait. See this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577365/python-selenium-explicit-webdriverwait-function-only-works-with-presence-of-elem